# Does the property of non-increasing slope be generalized to a concave function for multiple variables?

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives, convex-analysis

For a concave function of a single variable, the following property is classic:

If $f$ is a concave function of a single variable, its derivative function $f'$ is monotonically decreasing on that interval, that is, a concave function has a non-increasing (decreasing) slope. And it is obvious that **if slope is closer to zero, it means closer to the global maximum**.

Does this property can be applied to a concave function for multiple variables?

For example, we know that the function $f(B)=log \left | B \right |$, where $\left | B \right |$ is the determinant of a nonnegative-definite matrix $B$, is concave. The derivative of $\left [ \mathrm{log} \left (\mathrm{det} B  \right ) \right ]$ is
$$\left [ \mathrm{log} \left (\mathrm{det} B  \right ) \right ]'=\left ( B^{-1} \right )^{T}.$$

Because we have constraint for variables, so the feasible solutions are constrained to several points in a space. My question is that **can we measure the slope of the gradient in matrix-form, and say that one point is the closest to the global maximum if some property of gradient is observed?**

If there is any related literature I will be very grateful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

A common characterization requires you take two derivatives and work with the [Hessian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix). I'm going to phrase this in the convex case (but the concave case is analogous, just multiply everything by $-1$).

By calculus, "$f'$ is always increasing" is the same as saying "$f''$ is always positive" (provided $f''$ exists). You have observed that this property holds for convex functions. More generally, the following is a common result:

If a real-valued function defined on a real Hilbert space (e.g. $\mathbb{R}^N$) has a well-defined Hessian, $H$ then
$$f \;\;\text{is convex}\;\;\Leftrightarrow\;\;H\;\;\text{is positive semidefinite}.$$
This result appears [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Functions_of_several_variables) and in most convex analysis text books (Rockafellar is a classic). The analogue for your concave case is that $H$ must be negative semidefinite.

To your second question, it still holds that $x$ (globally) minimizes a convex function $f$ if and only if $\nabla f(x)=0$. Equivalently, $x$ (globally) maximizes a concave function $f$ if and only if $\nabla f(x)=0$. This is known as Fermat's rule, or a first-order condition.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but my question is not fully answered (my fault for describing my question poorly). Because I have some constraints on the variables, the feasible solutions are not a complete real Hilbert space. In my question, my feasible solutions may be several points in the space and I want to find the point which is closest to the optimum. In one-dimension concave function, we have the property that if $f'$ closer to zero, $f$ is closer to the optimum. So I am considering is there similar concept for a concave function for multiple variables ?

Comment: When you say "$f'$ closer to zero, $f$ is closer to the optimum," do you mean "if $f'(x)$ is close to zero, then $x$ is close to the global optimum $x^*$, or do you mean "if $f'(x)$ is close to zero, the value  $f(x)$ is close to the global optimum $\textrm{max}_{x} f(x)$? I'd need to doublecheck a reference, but I think the first statement is true, but there are counterexamples to the second.

Comment: My question is the second statement. And this surprises me because I think these two statements are true. Is there counterexamples to the second statement ?

Comment: Consider minimizing $\epsilon|\cdot|$ for small $\epsilon.$ The slope magnitude remains constantly $\epsilon$ almost everywhere, and this value is independent of both the distance to the minimizer and the function value. In my last comment, I was thinking of a different (mostly unrelated) counterexample which states "there are sequences $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that the distance to a solution $\|x_n-x^*\|\to+\infty$ while $f(x_n)$ goes to the optimum."

Comment: Oh, I was wrong before. Thanks for your explanation. It is very clear!